Washing machine stops before wash cycle
I've had 4 machines installed at my home. They fill and fill and fill but never go to wash cycle. Both hot and cold water are getting to machines. Machine is outside in a shed and uses an extension cord.
I've changed cord out, no help. I had a tech come out and he said it was the control panel. But not on 4 machines. Currently, I have no machine installed. I'm at my wits end. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Assuming these 4 machines were not all from the same lot number from the same manufacturer and therefore all having the same failure, I'd say the common item among all 4 failures is the shed/extension cord. 'Going to wash' is when the heavy electrical draw starts. If the extension cord gauge is not thick enough, the higher draw could cause excessive voltage drop in the cord and drive final voltage at the machine lower than the electrics inside can handle. Test: bring the machine up to your house where the extension cord is not necessary to power it. Does the machine start washing?

If they were purchased new, and recently,  I would contact the manufacturer for warranty service rather than spending my own time and effort trying to debug this.

I would be taking a very hard look at that extension cord. I think all 4 machines stop when they try to rotate the drum because the extension cord can't deliver the needed power due to quality or length.  It would be easy to spend more money messing around with lousy and dangerous ways to do it, than simply do it the code legal way with buried conduit and proper wires inside the conduit to a subpanel etc.

"Machine is outside in a shed and uses an extension cord."

Does temperature ever go below freezing in your locale? If so, that would destroy the machines from water expansion. Even much below 20°C would make grease thicker, harder to start turning.

Depending on cord length, you might need a 2 mm (12 Gauge AWS/B&S), 2.5 mm (10 Gauge) or heavier conductor cord. The initial startup (locked-rotor) current of a motor might be more than five times the running current. As an example, a 360 W (1/2 HP) motor would have a running current of 3 A at 120 VAC, or 1.5 A at 240 VAC. At startup, it might draw 20 A at 120 VAC, or 10 A at 240 VAC, with some of the voltage dropped across a sub-standard extension cord. The motor simply cannot start without more power.


Both issues could lead to the problem of the motor being unable to start when the machine is full of water. Also, consider the safety issue of permanent use of an extension cord to an outside building. This could be a serious hazard!
